# JavaScript object reference

Tags: javascript

I'm having an issue with Javascript object literals.

I would like to reference the object within one of the functions:

```
var Obj = {
    name : "Johnny",
    dumb : function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
```

Sadly, the "dumb" function is an object as well.  So, since dumb() has no
'name' property, it will return as undefined.

How do I get around this?

Comment: JSON is a data format that is a subset of JS object literal syntax. That isn't what you have (among many other things, it doesn't support functions)

Comment: But it works: http://jsfiddle.net/damirR/aF63T/

Comment: How do you call it? `Obj.dumb()` alerts `Johnny` for me.

Comment: What problem are you having?  How are you calling `dumb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dumb` is a method on your Obj object.  When called, `this` will be set to `Obj`, and will alert "Johnny"

[Try it out](http://jsfiddle.net/q4epq/)

```
var Obj = {
    name : "Johnny",
    dumb : function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}

Obj.dumb();
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is fine. The call to `dumb` should be:

```
Obj.dumb(); // "Johnny"
```

`this` in JavaScript is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where the function is defined. If you call a function via an object property, within the call `this` will refer to the object. So for instance, if you did this:

```
var f = Obj.dumb;
f(); // "undefined"
```

...then you get `undefined` (well, probably), because you haven't set any specific value for `this`. In the absense of a specific value, the global object is used. (`window`, on browsers.)

You can also set `this` by using the `call` or `apply` features of JavaScript functions:

```
var f = Obj.dumb;
f.call(Obj); // "Johnny"
```

The first argument to `call` (and to `apply`) is the object to use as `this`. (With `call`, any subsequent arguments are passed to the function, so `f.call(Obj, 1);` would effectively be `Obj.dumb(1);`. With `apply`, the second argument is an *array* to use as the arguments for the function, so `f.apply(Obj, [1]);` would effectively be `Obj.dumb(1);`.)

More reading:

- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: You can also use `.bind`: `var f = Obj.dumb.bind(Obj);  f();` :-)

Comment: @Rocket: True, at least on ES5 browsers (or if you use a shim).

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm missing the problem here.  Your code works fine.

```
var Obj = {
    name : "Johnny",
    dumb : function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
Obj.dumb();  // Alerts 'Johnny'
```

This is because `dumb` is called on `Obj` which is set to `this`.

EDIT: If you did the following, it would be `undefined`:

```
var x = Obj.dumb;
x(); // Alerts ''
```

This is because `this` is now `window` (as the function is not being called on `Obj` anymore).

You'd have to either [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var x = Obj.dumb;
x.call(Obj); // Alerts 'Johnny'
```

Or [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (ECMAScript 5, meaning modern browsers only):

```
var x = Obj.dumb.bind(Obj);
x.call(); // Alerts 'Johnny'
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in JS is an object. `this` is not "the function being called" it is the object it is being called on (unless you use something like `apply()` to mess with that).

```
Obj.dumb();
```

will have `this === Obj` so `this.name` will resolve to `"Johnny"`.

Just make sure you call `Obj.dumb()` and don't do something like:

```
// This won't work
var foo = Obj.dumb;
foo();
```

… as, while `foo` will be the same function as `dumb`, the context is different (and `this` will be the default object: `window`).

Comment: *"Everything in JS is an object."* Not *quite*. Nearly everything, but we do have primitives (strings that aren't `String`s, numbers that aren't `Number`s).